# Fastest way to retrieve a <title> in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing

I'm doing a bookmarking system and looking for the fastest (easiest) way to retrieve a page's title with PHP.

It would be nice to have something like `$title = page_title($url)`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
<?php
    function page_title($url) {
        $fp = file_get_contents($url);
        if (!$fp) 
            return null;

        $res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
        if (!$res) 
            return null; 

        // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
        $title = trim($title);
        return $title;
    }
?>
```

Gave 'er a whirl on the following input:

```
print page_title("http://www.google.com/");
```

Outputted: Google

Hopefully general enough for your usage. If you need something more powerful, it might not hurt to invest a bit of time into researching HTML parsers.

EDIT: Added a bit of error checking. Kind of rushed the first version out, sorry.

Comment: I'm relatively sure that will produce an error if the pattern isn't found. Initialise $title first, assign preg_match() to a boolean and check for that before attempting to access the first element of the $title_matches array.

Comment: Oh. Too right. If preg_match doesn't get a result, the reference to $title_matches will barf. Will tidy up a bit.

Comment: Facebook's title tags look like this: `<title id="pageTitle">`

Answer (score 20):

You can get it without reg expressions:

```
$title = '';
$dom = new DOMDocument();

if($dom->loadHTMLFile($urlpage)) {
    $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("title");
    if ($list->length > 0) {
        $title = $list->item(0)->textContent;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the first solution that works with deadspin.com

Comment: You may want to call

    `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`

before using `DOMDocument`.

Unfortunately, the underlying library `DOMDocument` uses to parse the HTML (libxml) as of today still doesn't support HTML5 (it's an XML library after all) and will produce warnings for HTML5 semantic tags (e.g. `<article>` or `<main>`).

There doesn't seem to be an alternative to error suppression here unfortunately.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6090728/2459834

Answer (score 12):

or making this simple function slightly more bullet proof:

```
function page_title($url) {

    $page = file_get_contents($url);

    if (!$page) return null;

    $matches = array();

    if (preg_match('/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/', $page, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}


echo page_title('http://google.com');
```

Comment: Yeah, I got caught once by a page with two title tags. Add the question mark after the asterisk.

Comment: Using `@`, really?

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews Man this is answer is from 2008, things were quite different back then. Fixed.

Comment: Weird, read 2017 for some reasons! Either way, it's never too late to get answers corrected since beginners might access it in the future.

Answer (score 7):

I'm also doing a bookmarking system and found that since PHP 5 you can use `stream_get_line` to load the remote page only until the closing title tag (instead of loading the whole file), then get rid of what's before the opening title tag with `explode` (instead of a [regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php#refsect1-function.preg-split-notes)).

```
function page_title($url) {
  $title = false;
  if ($handle = fopen($url, "r"))  {
    $string = stream_get_line($handle, 0, "</title>");
    fclose($handle);
    $string = (explode("<title", $string))[1];
    if (!empty($string)) {
      $title = trim((explode(">", $string))[1]);
    }
  }
  return $title;
}
```

*Last `explode` thanks to PlugTrade's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49470414/2199369) who reminded me that title tags can have attributes.*

Answer (score 5):

Regex?

Use [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) to get the $htmlSource variable's contents.

```
preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/iU', $htmlSource, $titleMatches);

print_r($titleMatches);
```

see what you have in that array.

Most people say for HTML traversing though you should use a parser as regexs can be unreliable.

The other answers provide more detail :)

Comment: perhaps it should be changed to non greedy to make it safer

Comment: But how do I get hold of $htmlSource?

Comment: In this case I think it can be safely assumed that a parser would be overkill.  /agree on the non-greedy matching

Comment: You can grab $htmlSource with curl or fopen.

Comment: I was looking for a better way to do that, but looks like most people use your proposed solution as a fast method to retrieve the title.
Please consider using the 's' modifier, i've seen weird situations where a new line breaks the regex

Answer (score 1):

I like using SimpleXml with regex's, this is from a solution I use to grab multiple link headers from a page in an OpenID library I've created. I've adapted it to work with the title (even though there is *usually* only one).

```
function getTitle($sFile)
{
    $sData = file_get_contents($sFile);

    if(preg_match('/<head.[^>]*>.*<\/head>/is', $sData, $aHead))
    {   
        $sDataHtml = preg_replace('/<(.[^>]*)>/i', strtolower('<$1>'), $aHead[0]);
        $xTitle = simplexml_import_dom(DomDocument::LoadHtml($sDataHtml));

        return (string)$xTitle->head->title;
    }
    return null;
}

echo getTitle('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399332/fastest-way-to-retrieve-a-title-in-php');
```

Ironically this page has a "title tag" in the title tag which is what sometime causes problems with the pure regex solutions.

This solution is not perfect as it lowercase's the tags which could cause a problem for the nested tag if formatting/case was important (such as XML), but there are ways that are a bit more involved around that problem.

Answer (score 1):

A function to handle title tags that have attributes added to them

```
function get_title($html)
{
    preg_match("/<title(.+)<\/title>/siU", $html, $matches);
    if( !empty( $matches[1] ) ) 
    {
        $title = $matches[1];

        if( strstr($title, '>') )
        {
            $title = explode( '>', $title, 2 );
            $title = $title[1];

            return trim($title);
        }   
    }
}

$html = '<tiTle class="aunt">jemima</tiTLE>';
$title = get_title($html);
echo $title;
```