# retrieving page title in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, page-title

Curious as to how to approach this same problem using ruby / rails - [Fastest way to retrieve a <title> in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399332/fastest-way-to-retrieve-a-title-in-php)

Is there a plugin or gem that anyone recommends? cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same spirit as the PHP tread, lets do this with no special gems:

```
require 'open-uri'
open('http://www.google.com').read.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1]
```

..and out comes Google

Comment: +1 for a solution that works. This wouldn't be the fastest though, `Nokogiri` and `Hpricot` (sigh!) are a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be pretty easy with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/).