# How to make a system which retrieves links and replaces the url with the relevant title name of that page?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Recently I saw that when I put the link in my profile it replaced it with the exact title of the question. So I want to know, how do they do it?

> [image: They replaced a url with the relevant link with a title as well]

I am guessing that they do this by sending the link via ajax and then make a link header by php `implode ,explode`. Is this correct way/same way that Stack Overflow does this?

Comment: +1: this is a very valid programming question IMHO? He could have asked, I would like to convert the link I paste into my textbox as the page title.

Comment: 1 close vote for off topic ?? and 3 for not a real question ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose I am pasting the above link in the textarea like this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444652/how-to-make-a-link-system-link-stackoverw
```

This is what happens behind the scenes. A GET request is made to the below URL

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions/12444652?pagesize=30&key=6AU78DZ)GcdjNjAszYmTLQ((&filter=!6G7RPxWUNTleV&site=stackoverflow.com&callback=apiCallbacks[%22stackoverflow.com%22]&_=1347774461814
```

The response of that GET is

```
apiCallbacks["stackoverflow.com"]({"items":[{"question_id":12444652,"title":"How to make a link system link stackoverw"}]});
```

From that one could retrieve the title. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 ,yes this is exactly  what is happening

Answer (score 4):

I thought this was too much info to put in a comment, so I just put it as an answer. The program just simply retrieves the value of the title element on that page.

So this is the basic process:

1. The program does a regex (or whatever) search for a url in the string.
2. The program obtains that url.
3. The program replaces the url with the relevant html code: ('foo', etc.)

**UPDATE:** This is how one would do the 3rd step with php:

```
$myURL = 'http://www.google.com';
preg_match('/<title>(.+)<\/title>/',file_get_contents($myURL),$matches);
$title = $matches[1];
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914573/how-can-i-get-the-title-of-an-html-page-using-php))

Comment: +1 for better approach by suggesting the regx and to know what is exactly going on see the naveen answer